# How can I check in RemoteFilte, if current node is primary or backup?

Tags: ignite

I have two nodes in Partitioned  mode and I use Continuous Query. When I put value to cache I see RemoteFilter is working twice (on primary node and on backup node). How can I check in filter if current node is primary or backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are several methods on [Affinity API](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/affinity/Affinity.html) to help you detect whether a node is a primary or backup. However, if the topology changes while checking the Affinity API, then you may end up on a primary node that became a backup or vice versa.

There is a way to check this deterministically, which is described in [IGNITE-3878](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-3878) ticket. This should come in the next release.